# Sum of columns and grouping by date

Tags: django, django-queryset

What would the Django ORM query look like to roll up the totals for each attribute and group by day

Table: Order 
Attributes

- order_date
- wants_fries
- wants_onions
- wants_pickles

*date         |   wants_fries  | wants_onions  |   wants_pickles
=================================================================*

```
2015, 9, 12  |      15        |     21        |      32
2015, 9, 13  |      49        |     9         |      22
2015, 9, 14  |      23        |     7         |      29
2015, 9, 15  |      7         |     20        |      35
```

Comment: Can you give an example of something you've tried?

Comment: Please post your Django models so we have something to work with.

Comment: This might help you: http://sohu.io/questions/2435323/django-how-to-do-select-count-group-by-and-order-by